# Separating my classes into different header file in c++

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have a problem with separating my classes into one header and one cpp file. Below is my main cpp file:

```
 #include "myclasses.h"     
 #include <math.h>                              
 #include <string.h>    
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <fstream>                             
 #include <stdio.h>                             
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <vector>
  .....my other headers....
 const int populationsize = 10;

Chrom temp;
chrom popcurrent[populationsize];
chrom poptemp;
chrom popnext[populationsize];
chrom popnextxover[populationsize];
```

And then couple of function definitions and then 
    int main {body}
I have myclasses.h header file as follows:

```
#ifndef myclasses_h
#define myclasses_h
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdafx.h>
using namespace std;
int Machines, Jobs,jobscp;
typedef class solutionset
{
public:
vector <int> indexinmilp;
vector <int>  indexinga;

vector <int>  startinmilp;
void resize();
};
solutionset problemsolution;
typedef class Chrom                                 
{
public:
vector<vector <float>> StartTime;
vector<vector <int>> Processing;
vector<vector < int>> t1;
int M;
int W;
float fit;
void variablesresize();
} ;

class Problem{
public:
vector<vector <int>> Processing;
vector<vector < int>> t1;
int M;
int W;

void setvectorsize();
};
#endif
```

And I defined the myclasses.cpp as follows:

```
#include "myclasses.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
vector< int> indexinmilp;
vector< int> indexinga;
vector <int>  startinmilp;
void solutionset::resize(){
    for (int i = 0; i < Machines - 1; ++i)              
    {
        indexinmilp.resize(jobscp);
        indexinga.resize(jobscp);
        startinmilp.resize(jobscp);
    }

};
solutionset problemsolution;


  void Chrom::variablesresize(){

    int i = 0, j, k;
    float a;
    std::vector<float> datapoints;

    std::ifstream myfile("Input.dat", std::ios_base::in);
    i = 0;                  
    myfile.open("Input.dat");                   
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> a;
            if (!myfile)                
        {
            myfile.clear();             
            myfile.ignore(1);           
        }
        else
        {

            datapoints.push_back(a);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    myfile.close();
    Jobs = datapoints[0];
    Machines = datapoints[1];
    jobisconsidered.resize(Machines);
    StartTime.resize(Machines)                  

    for (int i = 0; i < Machines; ++i)

    {
        StartTime[i].resize(Jobs);  
        jobisconsidered[i].reserve(Jobs);

    }
}

void Problem::setvectorsize()
{ 
    Processing.resize(Machines);
    t1.resize(Machines);

    for (int i = 0; i < Machines; ++i)
    {
        Processing[i].resize(Jobs);
        t1[i].resize(Jobs);
    }

};
```

However I see couple of errors when I run it in visual studio. I check other threads in related to this question such as [Difference between implementing a class inside a .h file or in a .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809679/difference-between-implementing-a-class-inside-a-h-file-or-in-a-cpp-file) and still cannot figure it what is the problem. In addition, I have some global variables but it seems I need to redefine them in myclasses.h header file and myclasses.cpp

Errors that I get:
First for myclasses.cpp:
For command  `vector< int> indexinmilp;` Errors include

Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

For command `vector< int> indexinga;` Errors include

Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

For command `vector< int> indexinga;` Errors include:

Error   7   error C2086: 'int vector' : redefinition
Error   8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

For command `indexinga.resize(jobscp);` errors include:

Error   15  error C2228: left of '.resize' must have class/struct/union 
Error   16  error C2065: 'startinmilp' : undeclared identifier

Or in command `void Chrom::variablesresize(){` I get below error:

Error   20  error C2653: 'Chrom' : is not a class or namespace name

Actually there are more than 50 errors. Maybe I made some mistake.The code was working well before this separation.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Please edit the question providing the errors you get.

Comment: "However I see couple of errors when I run it" - and how do you expect us to be able to help you when you don't tell us *what* those errors are?

Comment: Get rid of `#include <stdafx.h>`, or put it **first**. It's Microsoft-ism that can do horrible things to your code.

Comment: @DeiDei added some of errors.

Comment: @Jesper0Juhl There are lots of errors. I added some of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not declare global variables in your header. You are creating a conflict between main.cpp and myclasses.cpp. Look up the "extern" keyword for referencing global variables.
2. You redefine problemsolution in myclasses.cpp.
3. You should not use "typedef class". You use that twice but not on the third class.
4. As stated by others, you need to provide the error details.

Comment: So I need to use declare them using external in myclasses.cpp? How about other errors that I just added them

Comment: Also can I use extern for variables such as vectors in the classes?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/499330/9733335

Otherwise, it looks like you have a lot of syntax errors. You need to step through and correct those.